# let user import a dxf in unity space from his computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, dxf

i am trying to create a simple 3d space in unity where a user is able to import a dxf file,
the dxf will have a coordinate system so it will also be useful for the camera to go where the dxf is located.
for now i only got the script onclick to browse the user's PC but i have no idea how to update the unity 3d space to import external dxf files

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;


public class importDtm : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
       string path = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("insert pit shell", "", "dxf");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Unity3d community page you can find the following sample code of el anónimo.
It shows how to import an .obj file in the game.
[ObjImporter](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=ObjImporter&_ga=2.163325823.2123287100.1599395021-956657900.1599246162)

Unity also supports other formats like .fbx, .dae, .3ds and .dxf. But it is not recommended to load these formats in the game. See entry of Programmer [Dealing with autocad objects in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482958/dealing-with-autocad-objects-in-unity).